# How to restrict the facebook sdk from redirecting to default facebook app in android?

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am using new facebook sdk v3.8 in my android application. It is working fine when there is no Facebook app installed in device. But if facebook app is already installed then it is redirecting to that app.

But I doesnt want my application to redirection to facebook app installed,I want my application to use the sdk login in my application.

How can I restrict my app from redirecting to facebook app installed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At [facebook developers panel](https://developers.facebook.com/) go to settings and change the `Class Name` of your app to an other one that can trigger the required login process. There is also some advanced settings that may help you.

I have not tried it but I guess it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Change the package name in Facebook SDK from `com.facebook.katana` to anything else in the `Facebook.java` class so that your application won't be able to find the default app. But I am not sure this is correct way to do this but worked for me.

Comment: You have changed the package name in Facebook SDK in Facebook.java file?